# Pass local function as parameter to global function

Tags: c++, templates, functor

In C++ is it completely impossible to pass a local function or functor to a global function? It seems like all signs point to "no". It seems like the simplest way to solve a simple math function implementation like an integrator:

```
template<class integrand>
void integrate(integrand f) {
   ... 
   f();
   ...
}

int main() {
   struct twofer {
       int operator()(int i) const { return 2*i; }
   };

   integrate(twofer());
}
```

or something like that. This fails because I can't pass a local object to a template. I know the new standard allows lambda functions to be used here, but I can't use the new standard right now. I really want the function to be declared locally, too, because I think it makes things readable, especially in the real code that this is a proxy for. I know I could put twofer in a class or struct full of integrable functions, but again I think that destroys the readability. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to build "normal function", because anonymous functions are supported only in C++11, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B

Comment: Using local types as template parameters *also* works in C++11. There are no real workarounds for the older standard, except put the struct in an anonymous  namespace outside main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pointers to member functions, but the functions should be static. That works for me :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef int (*Integrand)(int i);

int integrate(Integrand f) {
    return f(2)+f(3)+f(4);
}

int main() {

   struct Twofer {
       static int function(int i){return 2*i;}
    } t;

   cout << integrate (t.function) << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing classes with objects. You can't use a locally declared class to instantiate a template object.

I'm not sure what you mean by a local function. There's no such thing as a local function in C++. From your code. There's nothing to stop you calling a functor of a locally defined object of a locally defined class. But you can't instantiate a template with it.

I don't know if that's been changed with C++11.